# Jump (jmp) in microcode with fetch, decode, execute and writeback

Tags: assembly, x86-16, instruction-set

I was assigned to do a jump or not conditional jump ("jmp") in which it receives the OP code and a constant "k" variable in which it stores how many lines have to be added to Program Counter to jump to the direction. Something as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I need to do just like a RISC pipeline (Fetch, Decode, Execute, Write back) for the jmp command. But actually Im not sure how to do this. Im pretty sure that the program counter has to be assigned the program counter and add the constant to it but how does this table would have to look like?. The problem is that this operations are created by my professor himself so this makes it even more confusing.

[image]

This is what I tried at first, but Im sure that MBR_i (Memory Buffer Input) can't be added to the PC (Program Counter) so this was just a failed try. I asked my professor and he said that decode is not optional but im not sure about the other ones, is execute and memory not optional too?. This is very confuse for me, **I don't know nothing about assembly so sorry if the question may look not very professional** but it is just for an assignment.

[image]

Comment: Is `k` an immediate operand, and this is a pc-relative jump? If so there's no need to read from memory.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be a relative jump but my teacher didn't specified, what can I write in the "write back" part? I was only doing fetch and write back something:

fetch: grab the data.
write back: pc <-- pc+ exp(IR)

where exp(IR) is the constant "k".

Comment: If you wait until writeback to update the pc, you'll have 4 cycles to cancel

Comment: So im supposed to update the PC in the "Fetch" right? That is what I tried at the very start, I did all in the fetch, but he said that we are supposed to use decode but I don't see where to change it. I don't know if you can give me some suggestions.

Comment: If you're pipelined then, sure update pc in fetch, but for jump it will be wrong, so have to update again, e.g. in decode or execute, and null out any instructions fetched improperly.  Need to look at pc+4 as a possibly wrong prediction, and when wrong looses a cycle.

Comment: what did your professor say when you asked?

Comment: he told me that it is a jump with a constant, he told also that decode must be included, i know that fetch and decode are used but I don't know nothing about execute, memory and writeback. I don't know how Im supposed to use decode when there are no operands in jump (or relative jump that it is what he asks for).